# What type of relationship would be between a customer and products? one-many or many-many

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I apologize in advance. I know this is a basic question. I am just trying to understand database design. What type relationship would between a customer and products if it's a eCommerce store like eBay or amazon? What is the best way to draw this relationship? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would say neither, because the relationship should be one-many between customers and orders. And order have many-many with products.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a many-to-many.  A customer can order many products and a product can go to many customers.

Comment: I mean't if he is selling the product. A customer can sell an iphone and an iphone can be sold by many customers too right?

Comment: It doesn't matter the verbage (sell, buy, order), the idea is still the same.  Take a look at [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365407.aspx) to get a better idea.

Comment: TTeeple is correct.  Any information relating specifically to the Product can be held at the product level.  Any information relating to a specific relationship between a customer and product can be held at the the join table level.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are trying to do:

- One to Many : One customer can have multiple product and sold in
  multiple places.
- Many to Many: one Item can be sold by many sellers    from many
  different sites.